# Codeigniter duplicates base_url()

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm having problem with Codeigniter which duplicates base_url. If i visit index page in controller all url are fine, but when i visit a page which is not index page in controller (cooling in my case) then i get strange duplicated urls like this one `http://www.mypage.si/www.mypage.si/services/colling`

For example

This is my services controller

```
class Services extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('main');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }

    public function cooling()   {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('cooling');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'www.mypage.si/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

This is my HTML

```
     <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('services/cooling'); ?>">cooling</a></li>
     <!-- results in: http://www.mypage.si/www.mypage.si/services/cooling-->
     <img src="assets/images/logo.png" />
     <!-- results in: http://www.mypage.si/www.mypage.si/assets/images/logo.png -->
     <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()."services/cooling"; ?>">cooling</a></li>
     <!-- results in: http://www.mypage.si/www.mypage.si/services/cooling-->
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: replace `$config['base_url'] = 'www.mypage.si/';` with `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.mypage.si/';` and it should work just fine

Comment: woow, i almost broke my head for this.
one more this, now all relative link which are written this way <img src="assets/images/logo.png" />
have links like this
http://www.hot.si/services/assets/images/logo.png 

how to remove services out?

Comment: prefix the `echo base_url()` piece to the front

Comment: if assets is in the root of your application, then you can simply add a `/` to the beginning of the url

Comment: oh, i was hopping i wouldn't have to do that.
Thx

Comment: oh yes again! The / thingy worked for me!
Thx again!

Comment: the reason is because without the `/` at the beginning, html assumes it needs to look in the current directory for the file and basically just appends the string to the current url. if you start with `/` it tells it to look at the root folder and follow the structure from there

Comment: if we dont set $config['base_url']  ='' still it works ?? which is the best pratices

Comment: I think the best practice is to always set $config['base_url'].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Codeigniter by default will not add the current protocol to your base url, to fix your problem simply update:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'www.mypage.si/';
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.mypage.si/';
```

if you want this to be a highly dynamic piece, this is what I currently have as my base url, and it never needs to be updated

```
$config['base_url'] = "http".((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "s" : "")."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/";
```

#### NOTE:

if you're using an IIS server, this may not produce the same results because the `HTTPS` element in the `$_SERVER` global does not get filled the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
$config['base_url'] = 'www.mypage.si/';
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.mypage.si/';
```

I also want to suggest `site_url` instead of `base_url` on view files. For example:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('services/cooling'); ?>">cooling</a></li>
```

Comment: Ahaha, OK, no problem :)

Comment: @Valor_ is right though, you should use `site_url()` rather than `base_url()` in view files, simply because if you ever expand your CI to include more than one application on a single CI install, then you'll have to go through and change EVERYTHING that used `base_url()`

Comment: will do! Thank you for advice